# Gzip freezes during the execution of ./configure command

Tags: kernel, configure, gzip

I am following the instructions of LFS book. I have unzip or untar many packages and install it. But when I do the same process for Gzip package It freezes. Everything is works fine until `checking for ld used by gcc...` part.

```
# lfs@harun-VirtualBox:/mnt/lfs/sources/gzip-1.9$ ./configure --prefix=/tools
.
.
.
checking whether lstat correctly handles trailing slash... yes
checking whether ftello is declared... yes
checking for ftello... yes
checking whether ftello works... yes
checking whether getcwd (NULL, 0) allocates memory for result... yes
checking for getcwd with POSIX signature... yes
checking whether getdtablesize is declared... yes
checking for getopt.h... (cached) yes
checking for getopt_long_only... yes
checking whether getopt is POSIX compatible... yes
checking for working GNU getopt function... yes
checking for working GNU getopt_long function... yes
checking for C/C++ restrict keyword... __restrict
checking for struct timeval... yes
checking for wide-enough struct timeval.tv_sec member... yes
checking host CPU and C ABI... i386
checking where to find the exponent in a 'float'... word 0 bit 23
checking whether limits.h has ULLONG_WIDTH etc.... yes   
checking for ld used by gcc...
```

What are the possible reasons for this? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I just find a workaround for this. But it is not a best way to solve the problem.  I execute the same command as `root` user it worked fine and not freezed. But this solution is not good enough. Because newly generated files by this command are belongs to `root` user. So we have to change ownership from `root` to default user which in my case `lfs`.

Permissions also should be recursive.

```
$ chown -R lfs gzip-1.9
```